# I want to add latest products in shopify portal on home page and product filter

Tags: shopify, product

I want to add latest products in Shopify portal on home page and product filter

Please suggest me how to do the same as I am new on Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

> Online Store -> themes -> customize -> add section

and add **featured collection**. You should see the collection in home page